# how to assign an actor to a lane in bonita 7.5?

Tags: groovy, bpmn, bonita, business-process-management

I want to assign an actor to a lane. I set a single user for lane from: Details tab, General window, actor. But the task was not addressed to the lane. What can I do to to assign an actor to a lane?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have defined the single user at lane, the default actor settings to the human task should automatically assign the task to that single user defined in the lane. The below steps should get your requirement done:

1. Click on the lane, General -> Actors -> Actor Filter -> Click on "Set" button - > Organization (from Categories) -> Single user (from Actor filter definitions)
2. Write your groovy script to return the user id. For example, if you want to return the user id by username:

   return apiAccessor.identityAPI.getUserByUserName(username).getId();
      // where username is the username of the user you want to assign the task to
3. Click on the User/Human Task, General -> Actors -> Use the actor defined in lane (default selection)